# Django cannot send email

Tags: python, django, email

This is the config about email in settings.py.

```
##--------send email config----------
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sina.com.cn'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@sina.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pwd'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = u'[Omret]'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

When i test my website on localhost by `./manager.py runserver 8080` It works.I can receive the email,but when i test it on the server (*django+uwsgi+nginx*) i cannot receive anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with port no 587.

Check the link below.
http://blog.mailgun.com/25-465-587-what-port-should-i-use/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it means that your server is blocking\limiting outgoing connections on 25 port, which is happening on some servers.